# Change background-color of div when "radio" is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the background-color of the parent div of a input (radio type) when the input is selected, but, if the user selects another input, the original div needs to go back to it's original color, and change the div of the newly selected input.
So far, i only made a function that changes the div color depending on the selected input, so if i click on another input, both divs will have their color changed. I searched for a solution for this, but couldn't find any..
The code is this so far:

```js
function changeBg(posicao) {
  var changer = document.getElementById(posicao);
  if (changer.checked = true) {
    changer.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCE00";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="posicao" id="um">
  <input class="input-posicao " onclick="changeBg('um')" name="posicao" value="um" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao" id="dois">
  <input class="input-posicao " onclick="changeBg('dois')" name="posicao" value="dois" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao">
  <input class="input-posicao" onclick="changeBg('tres')" name="posicao" value="tres" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao">
  <input class="input-posicao" onclick="changeBg('quatro')" name="posicao" value="quatro" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao">
  <input class="input-posicao" onclick="changeBg('cinco')" name="posicao" value="cinco" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao">
  <input class="input-posicao" onclick="changeBg('seis')" name="posicao" value="seis" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao">
  <input class="input-posicao" onclick="changeBg('sete')" name="posicao" value="sete" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao">
  <input class="input-posicao" onclick="changeBg('oito')" name="posicao" value="oito" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="posicao">
  <input class="input-posicao" onclick="changeBg('nove')" name="posicao" value="nove" type="radio">
</div>
```

In the print, you can see what happens if i select 2 inputs..

[image]

Comment: Before setting the clicked one to yellow, reset all nine to gray.

Comment: Hmm.. but wouldn't this consume to much memory ? or it wouldn't matter because it's such a small thing to do ?

Comment: No. The memory it consumes is 36 bytes. An average PC has about 8589934592 bytes of RAM. There are two alternatives: changing the color to "" should revert to the color set by your CSS. Or you can store the currently selected square, and when a new one is clicked, reset only the stored one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to attach an event listener to each radio button. Just create a wrapper around each and listen for the `change` event there (Event Delegation).

And the styling can be done through css with e.g. an `active` class.
The `active` can be removed from the previously active element. And then added to the currently active one.

```js
document.querySelector('.radiogroup').addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
  // evt.currentTarget is the .radiogroup element
  // and we search for all elements with the active class
  evt.currentTarget
    .querySelectorAll('.active')
    .forEach(element => {
      // remove the active class from those elements
      element.classList.remove('active')
    })
  
  
  // in this simple case evt.target is the radio button 
  // that became active for more complex event delegation you
  // need to check what evt.target is.
  // search for the ascendant with the class posicao
  // and add the active class to it
  evt.target
    .closest('.posicao')
    .classList.add('active');
}, true);
```

```css
.posicao {
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="radiogroup">
  <div class="posicao">
    <input name="posicao" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="posicao">
    <input name="posicao" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="posicao">
    <input name="posicao" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="posicao">
    <input name="posicao" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="posicao">
    <input name="posicao" type="radio">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: When no second parameter is passed to `.addEventListener()`, `true` is the default.

Answer (score 1):

First of all its not a good practice to call functions inline in the html file, add an event listener in you script and handle user inputs there:

```
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
radios.forEach(radio => {
   radio.onclick = () => {
      radios.forEach(radio => {
         radio.style.backgroundColor = radio.checked ? '#FFCE00' : '#ffffff';
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: I know, i didn't put the JS in the HTML file, some one edited the question so it looked like this.. but the goal of the question is to know how to do it, that's all

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a working vanilla js function for your prob.

But You have missed id from sencond 'posicao' div to last, add the correct id.

```
function changeBg(id) {
        let changer = document.getElementById(id);
        let all = document.getElementsByClassName('posicao');
        console.log(all);
          for (let i =0; i<all.length; i++){
              all[i].classList.remove('color')
          }
        changer.classList.add("color");
        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes.. i forgot to edit to make it right.. but if it worked on 2 divs, it would work on 100....